# JQuery Validation error message fadein

Tags: javascript, jquery-validate

i need your help. I am not very far from the solution but how can i make the errors messages display with a fade in instead of the normal way. I have this code already, i think i am very close to the solution.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#contactform").validate({
  errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
     error.fadeIn('.error');
  },
        messages: {
            contactname: "Required",
            email: "Invalid email",
            comment: "Invalid URL"
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: It would help out a lot if you said what validation plugin you were using.

Comment: I am using this one http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.8.1/jquery.validate.js thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function() {
    $("#contactForm").validate({
        invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {
            // not sure if this is the correct selector but I found it here: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions
            $(".error").hide().fadeIn("slow");
        },
        messages: {
            contactname: "Required",
            email: "Invalid email",
            comment: "Invalid URL"
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: No, it doesnt work. You can see all my code here:  http://jsfiddle.net/CEscorcio/CdvGh/2/

Comment: Can you put an alert box in and check if 'invalidHandler' is firing?

Comment: Well, the only thing I can see that is incorrect with the script is that I used 'contractForm' instead of 'contactForm'

Comment: it´s already firing but the fade is not happening, i am trying just to hide and it doesnt hide. Thanks  $(".error").hide().fadeIn("slow");

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
error.fadeIn('.error');
```

Try:

```
$('.error').text(error).fadeIn();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add a section like this in your script below messages

```
highlight: function (element, errorClass) {                    
                    $('label[for=' + element.id + ']').hide();
                    $('label[for=' + element.id + ']').fadeIn(5000);

                },
```

Answer (score 0):

your code in jsfiddle does not work.
Here is the solution.

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        var c = $("<span style='display: none'/>").append(error.html());
        error.empty().append(c);
        setTimeout(function(){ error.children().first().fadeIn("slow");},0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@John Kalberer This worked for me just fine ...

thanks,,

> $(function() {
>       $("#contactForm").validate({
>           invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {
>               // not sure if this is the correct selector but I found it here: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions
>               $(".error").hide().fadeIn("slow");
>           },
>           messages: {
>               contactname: "Required",
>               email: "Invalid email",
>               comment: "Invalid URL"
>           }
>       }); });